# SQLite - Group by multiple columns, count distinct of one

Tags: sqlite, count, group-by, distinct

Say I have the following table:

```
Commit File    Past_Author
1       a      Alice
1       a      Bob
1       a      Bob
1       b      Alice
```

I'm looking to count the number of distinct authors for each file, summed by commit.  In this case, I'd want 3 authors for commit 1 (2 for file a + 1 for file b).

I guess something like: `SELECT Commit, SUM(NUM_AUTHORS) FROM (SELECT Commit, File, COUNT(DISTINT Past_Author) as NA FROM COMMITS GROUP BY File) GROUP BY Commit`

Comment: The `group by` in your subquery is incorrect. You have to `GROUP BY` file and commit.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
SELECT Commit, SUM(NUM_AUTHORS) FROM
(
   SELECT 
      Commit, 
      File,
      COUNT(DISTINCT Past_Author) AS NUM_AUTHORS
   FROM COMMITS
   GROUP BY Commit, File
) AS AUTHOR_COUNT
GROUP BY Commit;
```